# SQL UPDATE statement - returns success but 0 rows affected

Tags: sql, mysql

I am sending an SQL UPDATE query, and the mySQL database is behaving strangely. It returns a successful response, but 0 rows are affected. The code is:

```
UPDATE place 
SET city='Qatar' AND country='Qatar'
WHERE placeid='25'
```

`Response: Successful 0 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.0003 sec )`

There is *definitely* a record with placeid='25' in the database. If I do a SELECT * FROM place WHERE placeid='25' I get the record returned.

Any ideas?
thanks!

EDIT:

```
Table structure:

SQL query: describe place; 
Rows: 9

Field         Type     Null   Key    Default  Extra
title         text     NO            NULL     
description   text     NO            NULL     
latitude      float    NO            NULL     
longitude     float    NO            NULL     
image         text     NO            NULL     
placeid       int(11)  NO     PRI    NULL     
country       text     YES           NULL     
city          text     YES           NULL     
address       text     YES           NULL
```

Comment: It's strange that the AND inside the SET is accepted at all. That should throw an error as far as I can tell. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name He uses mySQL.

Comment: Hmm, so how is this strange syntax "translated" by MySQL. What does MySQL make out of that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with this :

```
UPDATE place 
SET city='Qatar', country='Qatar'
WHERE placeid=25
```

Because your **`AND`** sounds strange in your query.

Comment: @Nishant : thx, I had a doubt because maybe in mySQL which is a DB that I never used this syntax could work ! Anyway, looks like my answer is ignored by @Will :D

Comment: Yep, it sounded to mysql like "UPDATE place SET FALSE WHERE ..." because the "something AND something" has been translated to a boolean expression.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that MySQL is 'smart' and does not update a record to a value that is already in database. When I run an update statement from Workbench I got the first time the response (updating from 'a' to 'b'):

> update t.t set s='b' where k > 0|1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

The second time I get the response (updating from 'b' to 'b'):

> update t.t set s='b' where k > 0|0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Fortunate the row is never the less locked in the transaction.

Comment: This is probably the real reason.  The UPDATE was malformed (AND instead of comma) and always setting the column to the same value because it was a logical AND.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure placeId is varchar but not numeric? have you tried without '' ?

```
UPDATE place  SET city='Qatar' AND country='Qatar' WHERE placeid=25
```